# Is there a way to react with my current code? (DiscordJsV12)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am relativley new to djs and I am trying to make a reaction role section for my bot.
Everything in the bot works except adding the actual reactions to the embed. I get the error:

> TypeError: rembed.react is not a function

My command handler at the top of the page is:

```
    if(!msg.content.startsWith('!')) return;
    const args = msg.content.split(/[\ ]/g);
    const cmd = args[0].slice(1).toLowerCase();
    switch (cmd) {
```

And my code in question is:

```
        case 'roles':
             msg.delete();
             const rembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
             rembed.setTitle("Role Reactions");
             rembed.setColor("#ffaa00");
              rembed.setDescription("<:logo:711299539717455983> - Discord Bot Updates\n<:twitter:711298466151923862> - Tweets\n<:poll:735344542177427497> - Polls\n<:poll:735345079543136314> - Network Updates\n<:tnt:735346109412540447> - Factions Updates\n<:sapling:735347737435832381> - SkyBlock Updates");
             try {
                  msg.channel.send(rembed);
                  rembed.react(""); 
         } catch(err) {
                console.warn(err);
         }
```

I have been trying to fix this for so many hours now I would really appreciate someones help.

Warm regards,

Hunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `msg.channel.send(embed).then(message=>message.react(''));`

Seen that `channel.send()` returns a promise we can use `then`, so that when the message it's sent we can add a reaction to it.

Comment: Amazing, this works perfectly, how would I add more then one reaction in this case?

Comment: Just use more message.react() methods inside the then function. Also, if this answer was helpful to you, you may accept it as an answer so that other people will quickly be able to find it. Thanks.